# with KEIL4 where the lpc2148 Interrupts or IRQs wont execute

Tags: c, arm

When the timer match MR0, run the interrupt service routine  At the end of the interrupt service routine. I don't return from service routine to main program.  Why does my program not return from service routine?

See answer below for complete code

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: i am working on one project, where i required the timer for interrupts generation. but when timer isr is called, its goes in the isr but it doesn't return from isr to my main code.

Comment: You have to show your effort, like code or something to make it more understandable so that people could get you more easily.

Comment: Are you clearing the interrupt request flag in your ISR?

Comment: For all we know your ISR could be `while(1);`. A question asking to reason about unspecified code is unanswerable...

Comment: NO, edit it into the question!

Comment: Does the handler not need an '_irq' qualifier?

Answer (score 1):

```
 the  code  is                                                                              /* Timer.h */
#include "LPC214x.h"
#include "main.h"

#define VIC_EN      5
#define VIC_TIMER0  4
#define MR0         0
void timer_init(void);
void timer_isr(void);


 /* Timer.c */
 volatile uint8_t flag; 
 void timer_init()
 {
 //disable and reset timer counters
 T0TCR = BV(1);

 //use T0 as TIMER: 
  T0CTCR = 0x00;

 //set prescalar
 T0PR = 15000000-1;

 //setup MR0 for 5 sec
  T0MR0 = 4; //4+1

 //enable intr on MR0, reset
  T0MCR |= BV(0) | BV(1);

 //enable T0 intr in VIC
 VICVectAddr1 = (uint32_t)timer_isr;
 VICVectCntl1 = BV(VIC_TIMER0) | VIC_EN;
 VICIntSelect &= ~BV(VIC_TIMER0);
 VICIntEnable |= BV(VIC_TIMER0);

 //enable timer counter
 T0TCR = BV(0);
 }

void timer_isr()
{
   flag=1;

 //clear intr in TIMER regrs
 T0IR |= BV(0);

 //clear intr in VIC
 VICVectAddr = 0x00000000;
 }

/* Main.c*/

int main (void) 
{
int cnt=0;
char str[32];
timer_init();
lcd_init();
lcd_putstring(LCD_LINE1," *TIMER* ");
_delay_ms(1000);
str_printf(str,"Count:%d",cnt);
//lcd_putstring(LCD_LINE2,str);

while(1)
{
    while(flag==0);
    flag = 0;
    cnt++;
    str_printf(str,"Count:%d",cnt);
    lcd_putstring(LCD_LINE2,str);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to define your ISR as `void timer_isr(void) __irq { ... }`  Without that, it's just an ordinary function and won't save/restore the extra interrupt context.

Comment: @Craig Estey Thanks ...after define like void timer_isr() __irq {   } .....its works. Thanks once again to all.